# How to load the whole list by fetching only 5 objects at a time, and activate that mechanism only for mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, onclick, load

I've been trying to make a website with a long list of items. For better user experience, I need this list not to load all the items at once, but in several parts, and only those really needed.

With the below code I have managed to get it working. It loads the data in small batches of 5 objects at a time. Next batches are downloaded only if the user clicks on "show more" button, and the button is visible as long as there are some more delayed items.

It works, but I need your help in is making this function work only on some screen sizes (let's say of width < 480px), since I do not need that whole mechanism with classic clients with large screens.

Also can I animate the list on loading to smoothly display when loading.

```
<script>
$('.list li:gt(4)').hide();
$('.show_button').click(function() {
$('.list li:hidden:lt(5)').show();
if( ! $('.list li').is(':hidden') )
$(this).hide();
return false;
});
</script>
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tristar2/7Sh6x/)

Thanks and hope for quick help regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a bash:

```
function checkWindowSize() {
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();  
    if (pageWidth <= 480) {
        $('.show_button').show();
        $('.list li:gt(4)').hide();
        $('.show_button').click(function() {
            $('.list li:hidden:lt(5)').show();
            if(!$('.list li').is(':hidden'))
                $(this).hide();
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        $('.show_button').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show_button').hide();
    checkWindowSize();
    $(window).resize(checkWindowSize);  
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but there is one problem that arises, the "More" button is still displayed for larger screen sizes, although they are completely loaded by default.

Comment: what's the markup for your more button? is that the `.show_button`? if so hide it in document ready. I'll update the answer

Comment: yes its .show_button , i tried your revised code, it doesnt seem to make a difference.. Also thanks for the previous code.

Comment: hmm, can you try now? It must be something silly. There's definitely no other code showing or hiding the more button? It might even be your css, if you have `.show_button { display: block !important; }` then the jquery won't be able to overwrite that, for example.